# Do I need to install ODP.Net? I am using .NET 3.5

Tags: enterprise-library

I am using .NET 3.5. I want to use Oracle Data provider in Data Access Application Block of Enterprise Library. Do I need to install ODP.NET? I am using oracle 10g client.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Oracle Data Provider for .NET is required.

Our software works with both SQL and Oracle. When a customer uses Oracle, ODP.NET is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to amend the Enterprise Library to use ODP .NET

This article should help you with this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DAAB_On_ODPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use ODP.NET without installing it by just copying the DLLs into your project's bin folder.

Basically you need to copy Oracle.DataAccess.dll and the dlls from Oracle Instant Client (which my change according to the version you have).

I DON'T RECOMMEND you to do that because those DLLs from Oracle Instant Client are huge! Over hundreds of MBs.